# create lambda signature after template argument

Tags: c++

I need to write a function (`f`) that accepts a `std::function` (`g`) with a generic callback parameter. In the function `f`, some additional code should be executed when the callback is called. I would therefore need to create a lambda with a signature depending on the generic callback parameter. My template skills fails me here.

So basically, in the snippet below, both `g1` and `g2` should be possible to use as input to `f`:

```
void g1(std::function<void()> cb)
{
  // do stuff, call callback
  cb();
}

void g2(std::function<void(int)> cb)
{
  cb(1);
}

template<typename TFunc, typename TCb>
void f(TFunc g, TCb handler)
{
  // in some way intercept the callback from g to do additional stuff when callback arrives
  g([handler](int i) {  // this only works for g2 now, needs to be generic
    // Do the extra stuff here before calling final callback

    // Call final callback with same signature as g1 (or g2) callback
    handler(i);
  });
}

void main()
{
  f(g1, [](){});
  f(g2, [](int){});
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but maybe you can use it as a starting point... This requires C++14

```
  g([handler](auto&&... args ) {  
    // Do the extra stuff here before calling final callback

    // Call final callback with same signature as g1 (or g2) callback
    handler(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
  });
```

Full example here: https://godbolt.org/z/xranbfrEE

If you can use C++20, you can use the new lambda template parameters:

```
  g([handler]<typename... Args> (Args&&... args ) {  
    handler(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  });
```